# Relationship between domain and quantifiers in predicate logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I'm confused about the domain of discourse and their predicates.

Lets say we have *Domain: {1,2,3}* and predicates *P: {1,2} S: {1,2}*

If we were to say *∀x(P(x) ∧ S(x))* would this mean, that for all entities that hold for *P*, they also hold for *S*? Or would this mean "Every entity in the domain holds for both *P* and *S*" (which would obviously not hold because *3* is in neither *P* nor is it in *S*.

Comment: *NB:* I suspect you have parentheses in the wrong place. Do you mean $$\forall x(P(x)\land S(x))?$$

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Sorry, will edit now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you meant $\forall x(P(x) \land S(x))$ (with $S(x)$ inside the scope of the quantifier $\forall x$), not $\forall x(P(x)) \land S(x)$.

If you say $\forall x(P(x) \land S(x))$, this means "For all entities in the domain, $P$ holds *and* $S$ holds". This statement is false in the domain $\{1,2,3\}$, since neither $P$ nor $S$ hold of $3$.

If you want to say "For all entities for which $P$ holds, $S$ holds", this would be formalized as $\forall x (P(x) \to S(x))$: "For all entities, *if* $P$ holds of that entity, *then* $S$ holds of that entity". This statement is true in the domain $\{1,2,3\}$, since for all the entities for which $P$ holds, namely $1$ and $2$, $S$ holds as well.
Here it doesn't matter that $P$ doesn't hold of $3$, since with $\to$ all we're saying is that *if* it is true that $P$ holds of $3$, then $S$ holds of $3$, and since $P(x)$ is false for $x=3$, we have by the semantics of $\to$ that $P(x) \to S(x)$ is true as well.

But this is not a question on how quantifiers work on domains that's special to predicate calculus, it's simply the meaning of the connectives $\land$ and $\to$.

Comment: Your assumption was correct, thank you! This has really bothered me, now it makes sense! PS: If you have a good suggestion regarding the title, feel free to give it an edit! :)